# Eclipse Console not printing until termination of program

Tags: c, eclipse, console

So I have just started to learn program in C, using the Eclipse IDE.

My issue is, that any output is not printed on the console until the program terminates.

For example:

```
int main()
{
int i;
printf("Provide a number.\n");
scanf("%d",&i);
printf("You provided: %d\n",i);
}
```

When running this code, the console will stay empty, although it should print "Provide a number.", obviously. Only after typing a number and hitting Enter the console output

```
Provide a number.
You provided: 7
```

is displayed.

I am using Eclipse Cpp Oxygen on Windows 10 and using Cygwin toolchain to compile and run the code. Any help?

Comment: put "fflush(stdout);" after each printf. Does that help ?

Comment: This is old and known problem with Eclipse console buffering. Add `fflush(stdout)`.

Comment: @Tom's
Thank you very much, this helped. But I am more and more growing the thought, that Eclipse on Windows may not be the best choice of C-developers.

Comment: Depends on what you are developing... For cross-platform development I find it close to perfect.

Comment: The next line character should flush it out right? why it is not so? I know it does in other environment

Comment: @Sudhee I recently learned that there is no guarante at all that a new line will flush the buffer. The buffering/flushing are implementation/runtile dependant (there nothing at all in the documentation about that).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
int main()
{
int i;
fflush(stdout);
printf("Provide a number.\n");
scanf("%d",&i);
printf("You provided: %d\n",i);
}
```

Comment: `fflush` *before* the output?